# In html, target="_blank" causing a download instead of opening a new tab

Tags: html, download, target, html-target

The lines of code below functioned for one week and then the files for "example3.log" began to be forced to download on some, but not all, PCs while using the same browser(s) on the different PCs and the files for "example2.out" began to display differently on some, but not all PCs, again, while using the same browser(s) across PCs. When I first wrote the code I tested it in Chrome, IE, Safari, and Firefox without issue. The code continued to function properly until about one week after creating the site. Additionally, the current errors don't appear to be browser specific (i.e., I've had, and continue to have, success opening in a new tab with the same browser one some PCs but not others).

Original coding structure:

```
<a href="sub_directory/exmaple1.pdf" target="_blank">Example #1</a>
<a href="sub_directory/exmaple2.out" target="_blank">Example #2</a>
<a href="sub_directory/exmaple3.log" target="_blank">Example #3</a>
```

I found some references to alternate html code such that:

```
<a onclick="window.open ('sub_directory/example3.log', ''); return false" href="javascript:void(0);">Example #3</a>
```

Unfortunately this code failed to solve the problem with the .log and .out files. Also, note that the .pdf files open in a new tab regardless of which version of code is used (original vs. alternate html) and/or browser.

Can anyone suggest either: (1) a correction to the above code, or (2) alternative coding structures, which will result in the each file type being opened in a new tab?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Open the console in the browser, after clicking the bad links check two things 1) Any errors being logged and then 2) Swith to the network tab and tell us what happens on the bad links.